# There is no sound with iFrameExtractor player

Tags: ios5, ffmpeg

I has built ffmpeg and iFrameExtractor with ios5.1 successful, But when I play the video, There is no sound

```
// Register all formats and codecs
avcodec_register_all();
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();


if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, [@"http://somesite.com/test.mp4" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, NULL) != 0) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Couldn't open file\n");
    goto initError;
}
```

The log is

```
[swscaler @ 0xdd3000] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from
 yuv420p to rgb24. 2012-10-22 20:42:47.344 iFrameExtractor[356:707]
 video duration: 5102.840000 2012-10-22 20:42:47.412
 iFrameExtractor[356:707] video size: 720 x 576 2012-10-22 20:42:47.454
 iFrameExtractor[356:707] Application windows are expected to have a
 root view
```

This is my configure file for ffmpeg 0.11.1:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

rm -rf compiled/*

./configure \
--cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='/usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk \
--target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=cortex-a8 \
--extra-cflags='-arch armv7' \
--extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk' \
--prefix=compiled/armv7 \
--enable-cross-compile \
--enable-nonfree \
--disable-armv5te \
--disable-swscale-alpha \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--enable-decoder=h264 \
--enable-decoder=svq3 \
--disable-asm \
--disable-bzlib \
--disable-gpl \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--disable-mmx \
--disable-neon \
--disable-decoders \
--disable-muxers \
--disable-demuxers \
--disable-devices \
--disable-parsers \
--disable-encoders \
--enable-protocols \
--disable-filters \
--disable-bsfs \
--disable-postproc \
--disable-debug
```

Comment: Hey I'm trying to build ffmpeg right now? What are your steps to building FFMPEG for xcode? I'm having some difficulty

Comment: @Jimmy You can search at Github, it's easy

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information here.

What url are you trying to open for instance?

Where there messages in the log. I know using version .11 you get a few warnings about you not including the network_init, but that wouldn't stop it from working. 
Some things have changed that worked in previous versions ie.  you used to be able to append ?tcp to specify ffmpeg is using tcp but now it must be done in the dictionary.

Please provide both the syslog and build logs if possilbe.

Here's an example from one of our apps

```
avcodec_register_all();
        avdevice_register_all();
        av_register_all();
        avformat_network_init();


        const char *filename = [url UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"filename = %@" ,url);
       // err = av_open_input_file(&avfContext, filename, NULL, 0, NULL);
        AVDictionary *opts = 0;

        if (usesTcp) {
            av_dict_set(&opts, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
            }

         err = avformat_open_input(&avfContext, filename, NULL, &opts);
        av_dict_free(&opts);
        if (err) {
            NSLog(@"Error: Could not open stream: %d", err);

            return nil;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Opened stream");
        }
```

Comment: Update!  Tt works now, but has no sound for any kind video (.mp4 .mov .ts)

Comment: again , you need to give us more information, perhaps some example of the code your using would be a good start, what are you doing with the audio samples after you get the stream for instance.

Comment: exactly, but as an exercise I just took iframeextractor converted it to use our framework and decoder, took about 15 minutes total, want to see it look here https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/iFrameExtractor

Comment: You use AVFoundation to play audio, but my audio is mpeg format, I want to play the audio by ffmpeg too :)

Comment: You could convert to raw PCM and use audio Units to play, if you want to contract with us we can help. Otherwise check out the audio unit samples on the apple developer site. auroTouch2 is pretty useful.

Comment: you are nice ! What is auroTouch2 ? Is there one url for information ?

Comment: auroTouch and auroTouch2 are examples posted on the apple developer sample page. if you have a dev account just log on an look at the source you will learn a lot. I think Apple's penalty for posting those samples elsewhere is be-heading or something, sorry :-)

Comment: Hi Michelle, thanks for your shared code on iFrameExtractor! I've tried to play an .wmv using your code, but not sound came up :-( giving me this log message: Error: audio format '' (86024) is not supported. Please, any help from you will be VERY MUCH appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: says it all what is the audio format for the wmv, understand that that was a very simple example that does no decoding and plays just baseline aac nothing else. There are other examples in that github that do however do decoding, and we have commercial  examples too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Michelle! I'll take a look on your Github examples.

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you do have a block of code like the following what do you do with the audio, you have to use one of the audio api's to process it, audioQueues probably would be the easiest if your dealing mostly with known types.

First in your initialization get the audio info from the stream

```
// Retrieve stream information
    if(av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx)<0)
        return ; // Couldn't find stream information

    // Find the first video stream
    videoStream=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            videoStream=i;
                   }

        if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            audioStream=i;
            NSLog(@"found audio stream");
        }

    }


Then later in your processing loop do something like this.

 while(!frameFinished && av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
            // Decode video frame
              //do something with the video.

        }
         if(packet.stream_index==audioStream) {
            // NSLog(@"audio stream");

             //do something with the audio packet, here we simply add it to a processing
             queue to be handled by another thread.

             [audioPacketQueueLock lock];
             audioPacketQueueSize += packet.size;
             [audioPacketQueue addObject:[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&packet length:sizeof(packet)]];
             [audioPacketQueueLock unlock];
```

To play the audio you can look at this for some examples

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/FFPlayer-beta1/blob/master/FFAVFrames-test/AudioController.m